# SELECT Latest Full Backup File - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Trying to SELECT the latest full backup file from a temporary table using the below query:

```
CREATE TABLE #fileList (backupFile NVARCHAR(255))

SET @backupPath = '\\ServerName\SQLBACKUP\Full\' 
SET @cmd = 'DIR "' + @backupPath + '"'

INSERT INTO #fileList
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @cmd 

SELECT @lastFullBackup = MAX(backupFile)  
    FROM #fileList  
        WHERE backupFile LIKE '%Production_Backup%'
```

However, it is selecting 12/31/2016 backup, instead of the latest. I believe the reason being is because when the data is loaded into the temp table it loads the date as MM/DD/YYYY instead of YYYY/MM/DD and SQL is only looking at the month and not the year.

Here is how the data looks in the temp table:

```
12/31/2016  01:04 AM    24,418,292,736 Production_backup_2016_12_31_000000_4880248.bak
```

NOTE: There's only one column in the temp table, so I can't convert the date to YYYY/MM/DD format.

How can I get the latest backup?

FYI-This is the link I referenced: 
http://www.sqlideas.com/2009/07/auto-generate-sql-server-restore-script.html

Comment: Is your date stored as a date or is it stored as a string?

Comment: The `date` type has no format. Most likely you used `varchar` instead of `date` when creating the table. Just drop it and rebuild it with the correct type. Storing numbers or dates as strings is a rather ugly bug

Comment: I wouldn't use that script if I were you. SQL Server stores backup history in MSDB, there is no reason to list a folder's contents. Check for example [this article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/11/10/sql-server-get-database-backup-history-for-a-single-database/) that shows how to use the backupset, backupmediafamily tables to retrieve the list of backups and find the latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set DIR options to this:

```
SET @cmd = 'DIR /O-D /B "' + @backupPath + '"'
```

By doing this it orders the data by date and time and removes all unnecessary formatting and only inserts the .bak file name like this:

```
Production_backup_2017_01_09_200000_9387961.bak
Production_backup_2017_01_08_200000_4133922.bak
Production_backup_2017_01_07_200001_2542266.bak
```

From there modify my SELECT script to as follows:

```
SET @lastFullBackup = (SELECT TOP 1 backupFile 
                        FROM #fileList  
                        WHERE backupFile LIKE '%Production_Backup%')
```

Answer (score 1):

This will convert the date portion of the string into a date and apply the MAX function:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(LEFT(backupfile,20) AS datetime)) from #filelist
```

Answer (score 0):

`Max(backupFile)` will order the `backupFile` in alphabetical descending order then picks the first record. Which will never get ordered in dates. Try something like this

```
select top 1 backupFile
From #fileList  
WHERE backupFile LIKE '%Production_Backup%'
Order by COnvert(date,date_col)
```

Store dates in `Date` data type to avoid the conversion in `Order by`

By default SQL Server keeps track of Full, Differential and Log backup taken in server. For more info check this question

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89278/get-last-full-backup-and-transaction-log-backup-for-each-database

Comment: How do I store the date if the date is coming from the Date Modified column of file explorer...the data that gets inserted is from a directory of a network path

Comment: @AznDevil92 - Alter your column to `DATE` datatype. This is the default format `yyyy-mm-dd`.